# Sed - Replace a pattern with a single character

Tags: regex, sed, pattern-matching

I have the following text

> I am really cool. I rate myself 10 out of 10.

Using *sed* I want to change the text to

> I * * *. I * * 10 * * 10.

i.e (Replace `[a-z]` to `*` )
I tried to use the pattern `s/[a-z]/*/g`

But it replaced the text as

> I ** ****** ****. I **** ****** 10 *** ** 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern replaces each lower case letter with a star. You want to replace as many consecutive lower case letters with a star. Use [`+` for repetition](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html):

```
s/[a-z]\+/*/g
```

Comment: Didn't work. The text is same - didn't change at all. - using cygwin on windows.

Comment: Worked with s/[a-z]\+/*/g . But what is the difference?

Comment: @anupamD, the difference with just `[a-z]` is that you don't replace a single character but all consecutive characters, which match `[a-z]`.

Comment: yes actually i was talking about using \+ rather than +; although you already edited it. Thanks by the way. :)

Comment: @anupamD, `+` will match the character `+`. `\+` will have the meaning of repetition. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @ndn is the right idea, but SED  by default uses Posix 2 Basic Regular Expressions, so you don't have all of the options of full regular expressions. In particular the `+` operator (repeat once or more) isn't valid in SED. Fortunately the `*` (repeat zero or more) is. Thus we can do:

```
sed s/[a-z][a-z]*/*/g
```

Which should do what you want. You can also enable full regular expressions with a sed command line option (`-r` for me)

```
sed -r s/[a-z]+/*/g
```